# Mongoose and MongoHQ

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongohq

why mongoose doesn't connect to MongoHQ I am using the given URL

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://' + user + ':' + pass + '@' + host + ':' + port + '/' + name)
```

it doesn't report any errors but nothing changes on database

Comment: I had a similar issue, my code would work when deployed (amazon s3) but wouldn't work from my dev machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to report errors, you have to handle the error situation.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://' + user + ':' + pass + '@' + host + ':' + port + '/' + name', function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

Comment: I don't need error reporting , I neeeded to connect but I found out that's it's server's problem MongoHQ doesn't support Mongoose

Comment: MongoHQ does support Mongoose...There must be someother problem.....see here: http://j-query.blogspot.com/2011/11/mongoose-and-mongohq.html

Comment: They support mongoose. I use it!